# Isolating, namespacing, sandboxing external HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html

Our webapp displays untrusted html uploaded by end users. At the moment, we display the html in an iframe, which nicely isolates the html from the rest of the site. Any css contained in the html can't mess up anything outside the iframe.

Unfortunately, the iframes are causing problems as we try to migrate to a mobile-friendly site. We're having trouble getting mobile touch event handlers to function correctly inside an iframe.

Is there any alternative to iframes for this app? We'd like to load the html into a plain `<div>`, but `<html>` and `<head>` tags aren't really valid inside a div and we'd have to play a bunch of games to get the css to work. And then we'd have to prevent the css from affecting anything else on the site.

We could try to sanitize the html, but we really do need to allow end users to apply their own arbitrary css to the html. The nature of the app requires it.

Comment: What about inline JS and SCRIPT tags? Would you allow them too? Probably not, therefore you have to sanitize.